# Finding parameter range from two solution sets

Tags: inequalities

Let the solution set of the following system of two inequations

$$x^2 - 4 x + 3 < 0 \\ x^2 - 6 x + 8 < 0$$

be a **subset** of the solution set of

$$2 x^2 - 9 x + a < 0.$$

How can I find the range of parameter $a$?

I have calculated both solution sets as follows:

```
Reduce[{x^2 - 4 x + 3 < 0, x^2 - 6 x + 8 < 0}, x]
(* 2 < x < 3 *)
    
Reduce[2 x^2 - 9 x + a < 0, x]
(* a < 81/8 && 9/4 - 1/4 Sqrt[81 - 8 a] < x < 9/4 + 1/4 Sqrt[81 - 8 a] *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making use of quantifiers, one obtains

```
ForAll[x, Implies[x^2 - 4 x + 3 < 0 && x^2 - 6 x + 8 < 0, 
2 x^2 - 9 x + a < 0]];
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> `a <= 9`

This differs from the Syed's result.